# update a listview when a new item is added to SQLite database

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, uwp

storing data in an SQLite Database, the data is being presented in a list view, when I add a new entry to the database how can I get the ListView to automatically update, currently having to close the app and reopen it for the information to update.

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        TestListViewBinding();           
    }

    private void TestListViewBinding()
    {
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.path);
        var Ingredients = new List<Ingredient>();

        {
            Ingredients = db.Table<Ingredient>().ToList();
        }

        TestView.ItemsSource = Ingredients;
    }
```

Xaml

```
<ListView x:Name="TestView" Grid.Row="2" Margin="8,0" ItemsSource="{Binding , Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding IngredientName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/ms668604.aspx) to replace your List `Ingredients` for the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView`.

The `ObservableCollection` provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed, for example like this:

```
public ObservableCollection<Ingredient> IngredientsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Ingredient>();

private void TestListViewBinding()
{
    var db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.path);
    var Ingredients = new List<Ingredient>();

    {
        Ingredients = db.Table<Ingredient>().ToList();
    }
    foreach (var Ingredient in Ingredients)
    {
        IngredientsCollection.Add(Ingredient); //This is important
    }
    TestView.ItemsSource = IngredientsCollection;
    //TestView.ItemsSource = Ingredients;
}
```

Then when you add data to your Database, **don't forget** to add data to this "IngredientsCollection", after the data is added to this collection, the item of `ListView` will be added automatically.

Comment: getting this error: 
Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'ObservableCollection<Ingredient>' is less accessible than field 'MainPage.IngredientsCollection'
do you know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: @matthewfuller, is `Ingredient` your data model's name? Make your model and properties inside for binding to be public.

Comment: this is the data model, correct? 

`class Ingredient
    {
        //ID
        [PrimaryKey] [AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string IngredientName { get; set; }
        public string Suffix { get; set; }
        public string IngredientCategory { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: @matthewfuller, yes ,try to add a `public` before `class Ingredient`.

Comment: just a bit of a follow up question, if the listview is on one page, and I'm adding data on a different page, is there anyway to access the same ObservableCollection from both pages?

Comment: @matthewfuller, you can try to make your `Ingredients` as a public static list, then in your listview page, create the instance of ObservableCollection  and add data from `Ingredients` to this collection.